Show all records from report via LWC
I'm displaying report records in an LWC page, but I'm only getting 2000 records, even though the report has over 10,000 records. It seems that the report data is limited to 2000 records. How can I retrieve all the records from the report? Is there a way to bypass this limit or paginate the results?
I'm attempting to display all campaigns, campaign members, and converted leads, along with lead conversion information, in a table via LWC by fetching data from a report. However, despite having over 10,000 records, only 2000 records are being displayed due to the report's limitation.
I'm seeking a solution to retrieve all records from report, or through a query builder from report or any alternative approach.

You can implement pagination or use a combination of SOQL queries and Apex to retrieve all records. - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387840&type=1

Can you please tell me how to implement pagination to get all records from report?
Since, I want all the lead converted information, where I am not getting by using SOQL, also I am showing conversion ratio, won ratio, total converted, amount, etc for this I need all report data.

I've resolved the issue by using a simple query on the Campaign Member Object, which now provides me with all the lead and converted lead information, along with campaign details. With this data, I can calculate the total lead conversion ratio and won ratio, as well as individual campaign ratios.
